# Tensor triangulated categories associated to schemes and their families

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory

For any essentially small, rigid and idempotent-complete tensor triangulated (TT for short) category $\mathcal{T}$ Balmer ([The spectrum of prime ideals in tensor triangulated categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0409360)) constructs a locally ringed topological space Spec($\mathcal{T}$).

When $\mathcal{T}$ is the derived category of perfect complexes, $D^o(S)$, over a quasi-compact quasi-separated (qcqs) scheme $S$, the construction recovers $S$ as a locally ringed space together with its structure sheaf from the tensor triangular structure of $D^o(S)$.

My questions are:

(1) Given a TT category, can we tell when it is equivalent to $D^o(X)$ for a qcqs scheme $X$?

Let's call the TT categories that fulfill the criterion *schematic*.

(2) If we take an essentially small additive category and put different schematic tensor triangulated structures on it, we'd get different schemes via Balmer's construction. Can all flat families of schemes of a certain type (e.g., smooth curves of genus $g$ over a field $k$) be obtained by varying the tensor structure alone?

(3) What are some natural discrete invariants of TT-categories and how can we build their moduli spaces after fixing values of the discrete invariants?

Comment: What does Nimas describe as a "tensor category"? I've seen differing descriptions as such in the literature.

Answer (score 7):

I don't have an answer to this, but this is too long for a comment.

As for your fist question, one thing to check is whether the resulting locally ringed space is a scheme. This doesn't happen always, as Balmer showed in his paper [Spectra, spectra, spectra](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.agt/1513715144) Proposition 9.7.

He concretely shows that the locally ringed space associated to  $SH^{fin}_{(p)}$, the topological stable homotopy category of finite spectra localized at p with smash product as the monoidal structure, is not a scheme. He does so by checking that if it were a scheme it would be the spec of the ring of global sections, which he shows is local and then compares the number of points of the underlying space.

I believe that you could abstract a bit how this counterexample goes and arrive to a statement with a somewhat contrived test to check whether the space is a scheme. It is my impression that the general suspicion is that triangulated categories of topological nature would hardly give you a scheme, but then again I don't know of very general theory on this idea.

However even if the space is a scheme I think it wont guarantee you the TT-category is a derived category. A semisimple abelian category is triangulated, so the usual tensor product on something like $k-Mod$ will yield $Spec(k)$ under Balmer's reconstruction, but $k-Mod$ is not (I don't think?) equivalent to a derived category of a scheme. But this example looks a bit extreme.

As for your second question this seems even tougher, the extreme case I can think of is when the derived category already determines the scheme as the Bondal-Orlov reconstruction setting, some discussion on the tensor products that arise in this situation was discussed in this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143644/can-we-define-the-tensor-product-in-the-derived-category-db-textcohx-j?rq=1) although this doesn't address your question per se.

Comment: @Nimas The Balmer spectrum of the stable module category of a finite group is the Proj of the cohomology ring, so there isn't a way to tell the stable module category apart from the derived category of a scheme just using the Balmer spectrum.