# What, precisely, does Klein's Erlangen Program state?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ho.history-overview, dg.differential-geometry, transformation-groups

People write that the [Erlangen Program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlangen_program) is a "program" (like the "Langlands Program"), i.e. a series of related conjectures, which in this case were all solved. There are various intuitive accounts, describing that this program is about relating algebra and geometry, about relating transformation groups of spaces (Lie groups) and different geometries, invariants, etc.

What I haven't been able to find is a precise statement in modern language (e.g. not that of his original paper) of what Klein's conjectures were. What precisely were his conjectures, or equivalently, what results constitute their resolution? Or was there never truly a precise statement?

Comment: I kind of tried this with the question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/59827/current-validity-for-erlangen-in-some-or-other-form . The observation underlying is surely that there is a "Galois connection" between the sets of theorems in geometries, and the (sub)groups determining the geometry. Mathematics of the 19th century was discursive, not axiomatic, so you don't always get the precision.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. There's an English translation of his program at arXiv:0807.3161.

Comment: What, *precisely*, does the Langlands Program over number fields state?  :)

Comment: Reciprocity and functoriality. Is that reasonable?

Comment: I'm not quite sure where you think the "conjectures" were. In any case  I like the thought that the real point was that this was the emergence of the "classical group" concept, which was probably *not* equated with a subset of Lie group theory. 

Comment: [What?! A user with nickname Berlusconi on a research level math site! It must surely be ironic...  (Apologies if that happens to be the user's *real* name) ]

Comment: @Davidac897: Please define precisely what you mean by "reciprocity" for a connected reductive group over a number field. 

Comment: I think this is tangential to the original question.

Comment: @Davidac897: I don't think it is so tangential.  My point is simply that the Langlands Program is really more of a philosophy, and it does not admit a totally "precise" formulation encompasses its many facets and special cases in a uniform way -- in other words, your emphasis on "precisely" in the title of your question is misplaced since not even the Langlands Program would pass such a criterion (though of course one can make precise many instances of the Langlands philosophy).

Comment: @Qfwfq: It isn't the user's real name, AFAIK :)

Answer (score 20):

For the historical part of the question, what about reading the (professional) historians of mathematics, for instance, as a point of departure : Jeremy Gray, Felix Klein's Erlangen programme, in *Landmark Writings in Western Mathematics*, ed. I. Grattan-Guinness, Elsevier, p. 544-552, 2005, which explains the circumstances of the paper and its main contents, and gives a bibliography.
Indeed, the programme was not a series of conjectures ! It states a view of geometry in which a geometry was associated to a group of transformations (not uniquely, of course), and (a part often forgotten) this also should provide explicit invariants. It was important because 1) geometry was still currently understood as "geometry" and not "geometries" at the time, 2) it allows to classify them and show the analogies/identity between different geometries (some quite bizarre to-day). As said by others above, from our point of view, a lot was not included, of course, for instance, Riemannian geometry was explicitely out of it (it was of the achievements of the Elie Cartan generation, and specially Elie Cartan himself, to integrate Riemann to this picture). The influence of the programme has been also studied extensively. Best, C. Goldstein

Answer (score 15):

Note: I am not sure if you have seen [this paper](http://www.mcps.umn.edu/11_6Birkhoff.pdf), but I post it here as an answer and I quote a couple of paragraphs, they are *not* my words! There is also [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/287647011X).

The first section of Klein's Erlangen Program (E.P.) announced its main theme as follows (E.P., 67): "Given a manifold and a transformation group acting on it, to investigate those properties of figures [Gebilde] on that manifold which are invariant under [all] transformations of that group." In today's language, Klein proposed studying the concept of a homogeneous manifold: a structure $[M,G]$ consisting of a manifold $M$ and a group $G$ acting transitively on $M$. This contrasts sharply with Riemann's concept of a structure $[M;d]$ consisting of a manifold on which a metric $d(p,q)$ is defined by a local distance differential $ds^2 = \sum g_{ij}dx_idx_j$.

Two paragraphs later, Klein restated his proposal in a single terse sentence: "Given a manifold, and a transformation group acting on it, to study its invariants.'' Thus Klein was also proposing to apply to
geometry the concept of an 'invariant' that Clebsch, Jordan, and their
predecessors had previously applied to algebra, and there only to the full
linear group.

Comment: This answers seems to capture the rough understanding I had of the programme. I recall hearing an even more simplistic formulation to the effect that 'a geometry is determined by its symmetries.' If some idea of this sort really was articulated in the Erlangen programme, then it seems to have rested on a very restricted (one might even say old-fashioned) notion of geometry. From the Riemannian viewpoint, most geometries have no symmetries at all. That is, from a modern perspective, such a statement is clearly wrong.

Comment: This is a nice answer, and coincides with my understanding of what the program was about.  Are there well motivated examples in which the [M,G] is not also an [M,G,d], i.e., in which there is not a local metric naturally associated with G? E.g., if G is rotations and translations, then it seems like the Euclidean metric is the only natural choice for d.

Comment: Answering my own question: projective geometry.

Comment: @Minhyong Kim: So Klein's notion of geometry is neither more nor less restrictive than the Riemannian one. Klein's includes examples like topology, which have no system of measurement, so in that sense it's *more* general than Riemannian geometry, not less.

Comment: I think one can place Riemannian geometry into something like a Kleinian perspective if one replaces "M" by the pair "(M,g)" (or maybe a triple consisting of M, g, and a coordinate atlas), and lets G be the group $Diff(M)$ of diffeomorphisms of M (which acts on the pair (M,g) by pushforward).  The point is then to study those features of a Riemannian manifold that are invariant with respect to change of coordinates.  This is to the original Kleinian philosophy as the general principle of relativity is to the special principle of relativity.

Comment: ... the point being that modern geometry still relies very much on symmetries; the difference being that the symmetries we use tend to map one geometric space to a slightly different geometric space (e.g. a diffeomorphism $\phi: M \to M$ maps $(M,g)$ to $(M,\phi_* g)$) rather than necessarily mapping a geometric space to itself.  That is, we use a symmetry groupoid (or category) rather than a symmetry group.

Comment: ... indeed, one could make the argument that category theory is the heir to the Erlangen program.

Comment: "They are the Riemannian manifolds of constant curvature. This idea can be nicely combined with Klein's classification of metric geometries. Regarded as Riemannian 3-manifolds, Euclidean space has constant zero curvature, Lobachevskian space has constant negative curvature, and elliptic space has constant positive curvature. Pursuant to the Erlangen Program, each of these geometries of constant curvature is characterized by its own group of isometries. But Klein's conception is too narrow to embrace all Riemannian geometries, which include spaces of variable curvature."


Comment: "Indeed, in the general case, the group of isometries of a Riemannian n-manifold is the trivial group consisting of the identity alone, whose structure conveys no information at all about the respective geometry."

see: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/geometry-19th/

Comment: @Terry Tao: If I was going to have Riemannian geometry characterized for me in terms of the Erlangen program, I think I'd want two separate pieces of information. One would be the diffeomorphism invariance, which is a global thing. The other would be that locally, the space has the same symmetries as Euclidean space (or Minkowski space). You could argue that the latter is unnecessary, because it's implied by the setup of the metric, which has a certain signature. But appealing to that seems to me to be contrary to what the Erlangen program is about.

Comment: That's a good point; a lot is hidden in the form of the metric tensor that one is adding to the manifold structure, and explicitly specifying the structure group for the asymptotic scaling limit of manifolds when they are blown up around a point would certainly be closer in spirit to the original Erlangen program.

Comment: @Terry Tao: I don't know if Klein would have agreed, but I'm sympathetic to the view that category theory inherits the Erlangen programme. If one allows the categorical generalization of symmetry, a version of the 'recover space from symmetries' view that is almost tautologically true is the Yoneda Lemma. In a different direction, there are a number of interesting theorems in algebraic and arithmetic geometry that allow the reconstruction of a space from an associated category.

Comment: Riemannian geometry (and many other types of geometries) is subsumed by the globalization of Klein geometry known as "Cartan geometry". http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cartan+geometry

Comment: I am surprised noone has mentioned Thurston's model geometries. They fit exactly into Klein's picture and are certainly of paramount importance.

Answer (score 12):

(Rewritten in response to David Corfield's comment below.)

A somewhat more modern take on the Erlanger Programm was given in Tarski's 1966 talk *What Are Logical Notions?* (published 1986), as described in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Tarski#What_are_logical_notions.3F) on Tarski, which proposes a distinction between what is logical and what is non-logical. The idea that as one loosens the theory (say from Euclidean geometry to affine geometry to topology to...), the relevant automorphism group becomes larger and larger, so that maximal automorphism groups (symmetric groups) correspond to theories of maximal looseness, where one is left with purely logical notions.

However, it should be said that Tarski's idea was clearly anticipated by F.I. Mautner, writing in 1946; see [here](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2371821?uid=3739808&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21101536120003). For some commentary on this, see [this post](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2012/01/logic_as_invarianttheory.html) by David Corfield at the $n$-Category Café.

As shameless self-promotion, I'll mention that James Dolan and I dabbled a little in this as well; some results were described at the $n$-Category Café, [here](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2007/10/concrete_groups_and_axiomatic.html) and [here](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2007/11/concrete_groups_and_axiomatic_1.html). There we give describe a Galois correspondence between subgroups of symmetric groups and complete theories, in categorical terms.

Comment: Todd, as I discussed at the nCafe - http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2012/01/logic_as_invarianttheory.html - the idea you attribute to Tarski of distinguishing the logical from the non-logical is there in Mautner. He was extending Weyl's Kleinian treatment of algebraic groups to symmetric groups.

By the way, any chance that you and James might pursue that very interesting work?

Comment: You are right, David; thank you. I'll think about how to rewrite this answer to reflect that. I do plan on renewing discussions with James soon, and will bring this up. 

Answer (score 4):

A small complement:

It is good to have a look at what the contemporaries thought about Klein's program
and how it articulated with the big deal of the time: classical invariant theory.
In particular Franz Meyer's review mentioned in my [answer to MO96140](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96149/invariants-for-the-exceptional-complex-simple-lie-algebra-f-4/96519#96519) is a useful reference in this regard (Klein's program is mentioned on pages 19, 42 and 45).

At the opposite extreme of the time axis, one can note that Klein's program continues to be a source of inspiration for mathematicians, see e.g. [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.5959) posted today on arXiv by Freed and Hopkins.

Answer (score 4):

[D. E. Rowe notes](https://books.google.com/books?id=fMHiBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA264&dq=%22Programm+zum+Eintritt%22) that one shouldn't read too much in *program*:

> Klein wrote it to fulfill a formal requirement incumbant upon every new *Ordinarius* who entered the Erlangen faculty. Its name, in fact, had nothing to do with a new program for mathematical research, but rather derives from having been a “Programm zum Eintritt in die philosophische Fakultät und den Senat” at Erlangen.

(Likewise [W. Killing](https://books.google.com/books?id=vjsdBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA1&dq=Programmschriften) and [many others](http://www.worldcat.org/search?q=ti:Programm+zum+Eintritt).)