Matrix invariants for simultaneous conjugation by a finite subgroup of $\textrm{GL}_n$
Let $K$ be a field of characteristic 0, and consider $d$ generic $n\times n$ matrices $X_1,\ldots,X_d$ where $X_k = (x_{ijk})_{ij}$ and $ K[x_{ijk}]$ is the polynomial algebra in $n^2 \cdot d$ variables. Then $\textrm{GL}_n$ acts  on $K[x_{ijk}]$ by simultaneous conjugation
$$
(X_1,\ldots,X_d) \mapsto (gX_1g^{-1},\ldots,gX_dg^{-1}) , \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  g \in \textrm{GL}_n
$$
I am just beginning to try to understand the theory of matrix invariants $K[x_{ijk}]^{\textrm{GL}_n}$, for instance with the Drenksy's survey COMPUTING WITH MATRIX INVARIANTS and Procesi's The invariant theory of n × n matrices. In the latter we have

The algebra $K[x_{ijk}]^{\textrm{GL}_n}$ is generated by $\textrm{tr}(X_{k_1}\cdots X_{k_m})$ for products of $X_1,\ldots,X_d$
The algebra $K[x_{ijk}]^{O(n)}$ for $O(n) \subseteq \textrm{GL}_n$ is generated by the trace $\textrm{tr}$ evaluated on products involving $X_k$ and $X_k^t$.
The algebra $K[x_{ijk}]^{U(n)}$ for $U(n) \subseteq \textrm{GL}_n$ is generated by the trace $\textrm{tr}$ evaluated on products involving $X_k$ and $X_k^*$.

and many more results involving minimal generators and relations.
My question is, what is the analogous scenario for $S_n \subseteq \textrm{GL}_n$ where $S_n$ is the finite subgroup of permutation matrices? Perhaps the analysis is much easier than the other cases, but I do not have a good reference.
An explicit description of these invariants can be found in Male's work on permutation-invariant random matrices, but there is no reference to this problem there. The invariants can be generated by what are called there the injective generalized trace $\tau^0$ defined on edge-labeled graphs.
What's interesting is that the equivariant maps on permutation-invariant (random) matrices form an operad, so there is a nice view of such maps and invariants. A broader question is whether equivariant maps/invariants for other finite subgroups of $\textrm{GL}_n$ also have some kind of operadic description, or if this is unique to $S_n$.

I believe that all these results are applications of the so called First Fundamental Theorem (FFT) of Invariant Theory of $G$, where $G$ is a specific group, which in your case is either $\mathrm{GL}_n$, $O(n)$, $U(n)$ or $S_n$ that your question is about. It's important to note that the FFT is not one theorem but the name for a class of theorems that are supposed to characterize the polynomial invariants of (finite dimensional) representations of the group $G$. Of course, each group is slightly different so the precise statement of the FFT and its proof are individual to each group. (Incidentally, once a set of generators for the invariants are known, a putative Second Fundamental Theorem would give the non-trivial relations between these generators).
It so happens that for the groups you are interested in, any finite dimensional representation is a direct sum of pieces that can be embedded in a tensor power of one (or a small number of) fundamental representations. For $\mathrm{GL}_n$ it is the $n$-dimensional vector representation $V_n$ and its dual $V_n^*$. For $O(n)$ it is just the restriction of $V_n$ ($V^*_n$ and $V_n$ become isomorphic). For $U(n)$ it is again $V_n$ and whichever of the complex conjugates and duals of $V_n$ are allowed and independent over your base field. For $S_n$ it is again just $V_n$. The representation that you are specifically interested in seems to be the adjoint representation on $W = \mathrm{End}(V_n) \cong V_n \otimes V_n^*$.
An invariant polynomial in $K[W]^G$ decomposes into invariant homogeneous summands. Any invariant homogeneous polynomial of degree $k$ is by definition an invariant element of $(W^*)^{\otimes k}$. By the preceding discussion to classify all such invariants, it is sufficients to classify the invariant elements of arbitrary tensor powers of the fundamental representation $V_n$ (and as needed $V_n^*$, ...). In each of these above cases, the FFT states that there exists a finite number of invariant tensors $(I_j)$, each belonging to some tensor power of the fundamental reprsenations, such that any invariant element of an arbitrary tensor product of the fundamental representation is a linear combination of outer products of a number of the $I_j$, up to (allowed) permutations (of copies of $V_n$, ...) and compositions (some copy of $V_n$ with some copy of $V_n^*$).
The result that you stated for $\mathrm{GL}_n$, $O(n)$ and $U(n)$ is a consequence of the fact that the only invariant tensor needed to generate all the invariants (up to products, permutations and compositions) is just $\mathrm{id} \in V_n \otimes V_n^*$. What distinguishes the cases is which of the fundamental representations ($V_n$, its dual and complex conjugates) happen to be isomorphic (thus allowing more permutations among tensor factors).
Finally, getting to the case of $S_n$ that you are interested in:

The FFT for $S_n$ states that the only invariant tensors needed are $I_1 = (1,1,\cdots,1) \in V_n$, $I_2 = (\delta_{ij}) \in V_n^{\otimes 2}$ and $I_3 = (\delta_{ijk}) \in V_n^{\otimes 3}$, where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta ($\delta_{ii} = 1$ and $\delta_{ij} = 0$ when $i\ne j$), and $\delta_{iii} = 1$ with $\delta_{ijk} = 0$ if any of the $i$, $j$, and $k$ are different. Actually, you can have higher order diagonals $I_k = (\delta_{i_1\cdots i_k}) \in V_n^k$ for any $k$, but they can be generated by the compositions/contractions $\delta_{ijkl} = \sum_a \delta_{ija} \delta_{akl}$, $\delta_{ijklm} = \sum_a \delta_{ija} \delta_{aklm}$, ... .

I believe that (at least the formulation of) the FFT for $\mathrm{GL}_n$, $O(n)$, $U(n)$ is credited to Weyl (cf. the reference to his Classical Groups (1939) in the Wiki link). AFAIK, the FFT for $S_n$ came only much later and is due to Jones in the oddly titled

Jones, V. F. R., The Potts model and the symmetric group, Araki, Huzihiro (ed.) et al., Subfactors. Proceedings of the Taniguchi symposium on operator algebras, Kyuzeso, Japan, July 6-10, 1993. Singapore: World Scientific. 259-267 (1994). ZBL0938.20505.

Perhaps if you unwind the above result for $S_n$ you will recover what's stated in Male's article. But their description was too dense for me to recognize the result immediately. They do have a paper of Jones in the bibliography: Planar Algebras, I arXiv:math/9909027, which doesn't directly cite his own 1994 article, but it does cover some similar territory I think.
Edit: It seems that a version of the FFT for $S_n$ was actually known much earlier. Namely, it follows by combining the Fundamental Theorem (Sec.3) in

Littlewood, D. E., On invariant theory under restricted groups, Philos. Trans. Roy. Soc. London, Ser. A 239, 387-417 (1944). ZBL0060.04403.

with Theorem VII in

Littlewood, D. E., Products and plethysms of characters with orthogonal, symplectic and symmetric groups, Can. J. Math. 10, 17-32 (1958). ZBL0079.03604.

Although I'm not certain how complete Littlewood's proofs would be considered by modern experts.

Thanks, this is very helpful. Do you have a reference for this approach using invariant tensors for each group? I'm still having a little trouble following how to formulate the problem this way.

@GregZitelli If you're looking for intuition and visualization, it's hard to do better than the "bird tracks" book by Cvitanović. More traditional presentations are in many standard references: Weyl, Procesi, Fulton & Harris, Goodman & Wallach, ...

Just a complement to Igor's very nice answer.
Indeed, Weyl is often credited with the FFTs of classical invariant theory for various groups, but the latter were known and rigorously proven before. Weyl's book rather is a, quite remarkable, synthesis and reorganization of previous knowledge from the 19th century.
For type $A$ representation theory, $GL_n$, $SL_n$, $U(n)$, $SU(n)$, I think the FFT is due to the collective effort of Arthur Cayley and Alfred Clebsch. The theorem says that invariant tensors (set $X$) are exactly the linear combinations of tensors built with copies of some basic building blocks like the Kroecker delta and the Levi-Civita tensor (set $Y$). There are two statements in the formulation of this theorem: $X\subset Y$ and $Y\subset X$.
The part $Y\subset X$ can be found in the article by Arthur Cayley
"On linear transformations", Cambridge Dublin Math. J. 1 (1846) 104–122.
The more difficult part $X\subset Y$ can be found in the article by Alfred Clebsch
"Ueber symbolische Darstellung algebraischer Formen", J. Reine Angew.
Math. 59 (1861) 1–62.
For explanations around Clebsch proof, see my two answers to
How to constructively/combinatorially prove Schur-Weyl duality?
For the group $O(n)$, the FFT is in the article by Eduard Study
"Ueber die Invarianten der projectiven Gruppe einer quadratischen Mannigfaltigkeit von nicht verschwindender Discriminante" from 1897,
(see page 443).
There is a classical adjunction method for getting FFTs for subgroups like O(N) from the ones for SLn. This is discussed in
https://mathoverflow.net/a/96519
and
The $GL(N)$ chicken versus the $SL(N)$ egg, the Erlangen Program and relations between FFTs
one of the questions I asked therein is whether this applies to the discrete subgroup $S_n$, but I got no answer.
